# bash script find nothing

Tags: linux, bash, unix

my script should search for a file but it show nothing, here is
the code from the 1. file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "" ]
then
        echo "search [options] file"
else
        /bin/search-help $1
fi
```

this is the code from the 2. file:

```
#!/bin/bash
find / -type d \( -path /proc -o -path */lost+found \) -prune -false -o -name '$1' & 
PID=$!
i=1
sp="/-\|"
printf "scanning  "
while [ -d /proc/$PID ]
do
        printf "\b${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}"
        sleep 0.1
done
```

Comment: `$1` should be in double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: `it show nothing` `printf "scanning  "` It doesn't even show "scanning"?

Comment: And it should be quoted in the first script.

Comment: When you fix the `find` command, the spinner won't work because the find output will overwrite it. You should probably redirect find to a file.

Comment: @Barmar thank you that was the problem. KamilCuk you must execute the first script than it works and change the ' in the 2. script into "